# Riot API server callback

Tags: php, laravel, riot-games-api

I am making website to organize tournaments in League of Legends game.  I have problem with receiving data about completed games from automatic callback.

The steps which we take:

1. We register provider with tournament-v3:

http://example.pl/riotcallbackinfo

on server EUNE

and recive id=10xx

2. We register tournament, and create tournament code successfully.

tournamentId=256xxx
code: EUNE043bb-xxx4d390-xxxx-4f2c-xxxx-4dc266xxxxxx
3. We play game with generated tournament code and completed it successfully.

4. After the match we should receive some data to our url:

example.pl/riotcallbackinfo

but nothing is sending. We have log system to check every time someone call this url and there is no information about calling it by riot api.

5. We can get data about this completed game using match-api-v3 and it is looked, like game is finished successfully.

We tried to register also http://example.pl:80/riotcallbackinfo url, but with no success.

To backed we use Laravel PHP 5.4. The documentation says:

"The following ports are forwarded to your Homestead environment:

HTTP: 8000 → Forwards To 80"

Lobby events for this game are:

```
{
    "eventList": [
        {
            "timestamp": "1498128797694",
            "summonerId": "23509512",
            "eventType": "PracticeGameCreatedEvent"
        },
        {
            "timestamp": "1498128833935",
            "eventType": "GameAllocationStartedEvent"
        },
        {
            "timestamp": "1498128803131",
            "eventType": "ChampSelectStartedEvent"
        },
        {
            "timestamp": "1498128798414",
            "summonerId": "34477543",
            "eventType": "PlayerJoinedGameEvent"
        },
        {
            "timestamp": "1498128834399",
            "eventType": "GameAllocatedToLsmEvent"
        }
    ]
}
```

We have tested our url method with Postman and sending your sample JSON response and everything worked fine. Even if our method is broke we should see something in log. Our log is set at the beginning of the method.

Could you suggest us, were could have problem? Why couldn’t we get data from automatic callback? There is problem with our URL or is something what we understand wrong?

Thank you in advance for your help